# How do I compare two tables in different databases

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two databases, which are basically identical running on the same machine.

I would like to compare the records in a table on database A vs the same table in database B

I would like to know which records exist in the table on database A that do not exist in the same table on database B.

Database A = "RICSTOREV341"
Database B = "RICHOSTV341"

The table is "Price_Tab"

The columns I would like to pull are F01, F26, F27, F19, F38

Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes, this can be done.*

You could use something like a three part identifier to identify the tables in different database. Kinda like this :

```
RICSTOREV341.dbo.Price_Tab
```

Then you can perform a join on the primary key and fetch the result.

Comment: This is what I thought... but I'm failing at the syntax.

Comment: Where are you failing ? Could you please update the query in your question so that I can take a look ?

Comment: Try Left Joining which will bring forth the data from only the left table. In this case. the table 341. Makes sense ?

Comment: SELECT COST_TAB.F01

FROM RICSTOREV341.DBO.COST_TAB A 

LEFT JOIN RICHOSTV341.DBO.COST_TAB B

ON A.F01 = B.F01;

I don't know why it doesn't work. Says The multi-part identifier "COST_TAB.F01" could not be bound.

Comment: As you have A or B as alias, you have to use them to fetch the multipart column name. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I did get this working. The query looked like this in the end. 
SELECT A.F01
FROM RICSTOREV341.DBO.COST_TAB A 
LEFT JOIN RICHOSTV341.DBO.COST_TAB B
ON A.F01 = B.F01
where B.F01 is null
order by A.F38;

Comment: RIght.. because we can use aliases to solve this purpose...glad its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solutions above - I can also suggest using some 3rd party tools for performing data comparison, and most of them have a fully functional free trial (like SQL data comparison tools from [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) or [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)).

These tools can help you save lots of time, as they can do data comparison and synchronization in just a couple of clicks.

Hope I helped.